# About GCP Console login audit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I wonder How to get "audit log" GCP Management Console (https://console.cloud.google.com) loggin failure ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To access the [logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) in the Console you must access in the dashboard to the Stackdriver tab > Logs. It will show the logs in the Console without the need of accessing Stackdriver webpage.